# Convert IP address from String to IPAddress (Arduino)

Tags: c++, arduino

I have an IP address that I receive as String (192,168,1,1) and I would like to put it in an object of type IPAddress. How do I do this conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arduino core class `IPAddress` has method `fromString`.

Example:

```
String s = "192.168.1.55";
IPAddress ip;

ip.fromString(s);
Serial.println(ip);
```